# Drupal 6 - force page view to display a different view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Kind-of a crazy question here...

I have a view display that's set up as a page. It looks great in theme A (desktop), but terrible in theme B (mobile). So I made a different version of the view for theme B. Since the desktop/mobile 'sites' are the same just with different themes, the url for this page will be the same regardless of hte theme selected.

So I would like to be able to point the user to:

mysite/this_crazy_view

and have the returned page select the proper view depending on which theme it's in. I know that if I were using blocks I would just assign the appropriate blocks to the page in question on a theme-by-theme basis, but since the displays are using page display I don't know what the right approach would be.

I would rather not rebuild the views as blocks if I can help it (if it can't be helped, so be it...) so I was hoping there was some way to conditionally load the view via the tpl.php file or something like that...

The code I'm using in my module (per @Clive 's recommendation below) is:

```
<?php
function bandes_custom_hook_menu() {
  $items['charley_test'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'bandes_custom_set_page_view',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM  );
  return $items; 
}

function bandes_custom_set_page_view() {
  global $theme_key;
  $view_name = $theme_key == 'mobile_jquery' ? 'course_views_mobile' : 'course_views';
  $display_id = 'page_5'; 
  return views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id);
}
?>
```

I've cleared the cache a number of times and tried a variety of different paths in the $items array. The course_views and course_views_mobile both definitely work on their own.

I was also wondering if I could just create a views-view--course-views--page-5.tpl.php which contains almost nothing aside from the views_embed_view(course_views_mobile, page_5) part? (Only on one of the two themes...)

Actually I think the answer was simpler than all of the above. The redirect thing was giving me fits, so I removed the module, reset the paths to what I had been using, and tried the template/theme approach instead.

This is: views-view--course-views--page-5.tpl.php, only used on the mobile theme, but referring to the non-mobile view (kinda gives me a headache, but it works)

```
<?php
//get the view
print "IM IN YR VUE, MESSING THNGZ UP!"; //yeah, I'm going to remove this part...
$view_name="course_views_mobile";
$display_id="page_5";
print views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id);
?>
```

Any reason that shouldn't work? (Or why it is a really bad idea?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me again :)

I just thought of an easy-ish way around this actually; if you can change the URL of your views to something other than the path you want to access them at (any path would do) you could implement a [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) function in a custom module for that path, to make the choice depending on your theme:

```
function MYMODULE_hook_menu() {
  $items['this_crazy_view'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_crazy_view_page',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK // or MENU_NORMAL_ITEM if you want it to appear in menus as usual
  );

  return $items; // Forgot to add this orginally
}

function MYMODULE_crazy_view_page() {
  global $theme_key;

  $view_name = $theme_key == 'foo' ? 'theView' : 'theOtherView';
  $display_id = 'page_1'; // Or whatever the page display is called

  return views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id);
}
```

That should do the trick

Comment: This looks promising! I think I'm missing one key point though (can you tell that I'm learning Drupal coding on my feet?) - where would the original path go? Or is that the this_crazy_view part of the items array?

Comment: Exactly right, the array keys from `$items` in `hook_menu()` become the physical path at which the callback you define in `page callback` is called to provide the page content. I actually forgot to add `return $items` at the end of that function, I've updated the code to reflect that

Comment: Let's say that I have multiple 'pages' on which I need to do something like this - would I need to make a custom module for each one? (I have my fingers crossed that this particular special case is the only one, but it's hard to know...)

Comment: I'm assuming that the name of the function doesn't much matter, right? (So I could name it something that doesn't necessarily refer to the path in $items? like, say function setPageView() or whatever?)

Comment: You wouldn't need to create a whole new module, rather you could just define another menu item in the `$items` array with the new path. And the name of the callback function is totally up to you, though Drupal convention would advise you to prefix with `MODULENAME_` to prevent name collisions with functions in other modules.

Comment: I put your code into a new module, and it's doing something, but now I'm getting a "too many redirects" error on the page it should be affecting..

Comment: Did you change the path of your view first? Sounds like you're getting a redirect loop because of two paths in the router table being the same

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the paths on the views were definitely changed to unused paths. Just to be sure I changed the path in the module to something bogus, and even when I hit the new bogus path I get too many redirects.

Comment: Hmmm. Could you post your code from hook_menu() and your callback code in your original post by any chance?